# Dynamic datasource routing - DataSource router not initialized

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-jdbc, spring-mybatis

I'm referring to this [article](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/), in which we can use the AbstractRoutingDataSource from Spring Framework to dynamically change the data source used by the application. I'm using Mybatis (3.3.0) with Spring (4.1.6.RELEASE). I want to switch to the backup database if exception occurs while getting data from main db. In this example, i have used hsql and mysql db.

**RoutingDataSource**:

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return DataSourceContextHolder.getTargetDataSource();
 }
}
```

**DataSourceContextHolder**:

```
public class DataSourceContextHolder {

private static final ThreadLocal<DataSourceEnum> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<DataSourceEnum>();

public static void setTargetDataSource(DataSourceEnum targetDataSource) {
    contextHolder.set(targetDataSource);
}

public static DataSourceEnum getTargetDataSource() {
    return (DataSourceEnum) contextHolder.get();
}

public static void resetDefaultDataSource() {
    contextHolder.remove();
 }
}
```

**ApplicationDataConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "com.sample.mapper")
@ComponentScan("com.sample.config")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:app.properties"},
                ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class ApplicationDataConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer =
        new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return configurer;
}

@Bean
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
    routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1());
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSource = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    targetDataSource.put(DataSourceEnum.HSQL, dataSource1());
    targetDataSource.put(DataSourceEnum.BACKUP, dataSource2());
    routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSource);
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(routingDataSource);
    sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("com.sample.common.domain");

    sessionFactory.setMapperLocations(
        new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver()
            .getResources("classpath*:com/sample/mapper/**/*.xml"));

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript(
            "classpath:database/app-hsqldb-schema.sql").addScript(
            "classpath:database/app-hsqldb-datascript.sql").build();
}


@Bean
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    PooledDataSourceFactory pooledDataSourceFactory = new PooledDataSourceFactory();
    pooledDataSourceFactory.setProperties(jdbcProperties());
    return pooledDataSourceFactory.getDataSource();
}

@Bean
protected Properties jdbcProperties() {
    //Get the data from properties file
    Properties jdbcProperties = new Properties();
    jdbcProperties.setProperty("url", datasourceUrl);
    jdbcProperties.setProperty("driver", datasourceDriver);
    jdbcProperties.setProperty("username", datasourceUsername);
    jdbcProperties.setProperty("password", datasourcePassword);
    jdbcProperties.setProperty("poolMaximumIdleConnections", maxConnectionPoolSize);
    jdbcProperties.setProperty("poolMaximumActiveConnections", minConnectionPoolSize);

    return jdbcProperties;
}
}
```

**Client**:

```
 @Autowired
 private ApplicationMapper appMapper;

public MyObject getObjectById(String Id) {
    MyObject myObj = null;
    try{
        DataSourceContextHolder.setTargetDataSource(DataSourceEnum.HSQL);
        myObj = appMapper.getObjectById(Id);
    }catch(Throwable e){
        DataSourceContextHolder.setTargetDataSource(DataSourceEnum.BACKUP);
        myObj = appMapper.getObjectById(Id);  
    }finally{
        DataSourceContextHolder.resetDefaultDataSource();
    }
    return getObjectDetails(myObj);
}
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource router not initialized
```

However i'm able to get things working if i'm using only one db at a time, this means there is no issue with data source configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try this last line once (in same order) :-

```
targetDataSource.put(DataSourceEnum.HSQL, dataSource1());
targetDataSource.put(DataSourceEnum.BACKUP, dataSource2());
routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSource);

routingDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Comment: I added afterPropertiesSet() and it worked. Any idea why that is the case?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue and found a solution using the SchemaExport class of hibernate.
For each DataSourceEnum you can manually initialize the datasource.

[here is my detailed answer to my own issue discription](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304146/5629762)